# pandas style background gradient both rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas

The [pandas style option](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.core.style.Styler.background_gradient.html) to add a background gradient is great for quickly inspecting my output table. However, it is applied either row-wise or columns-wise. Would it be possible to apply it to the whole dataframe at once?

EDIT: A minimum working example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3,2,10,4],[20,1,3,2],[5,4,6,1]])
df.style.background_gradient()
```

Comment: Did you try setting `axis=None`?

Comment: I did now, but it throws an error.. Good idea though ;-)

Comment: What kind of error? Could you share your code and a small snippet of the dataframe?

Comment: I added an example. The error message upon adding `axis=None` is: `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: From what I know, you can't set the `background_gradient` for both the rows/columns simultaneously. But however you could create a custom function and apply colors to a particular threshold of the values you want to distinguish them by.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Currently you can't set the `background_gradient` for both the rows/columns simultaneously as pointed by [Nickil Maveli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6207849/nickil-maveli). The trick is to customize the [pandas function background_gradient](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/29d81f3df81eb0a4d077ae1317df74d509cdc446/pandas/formats/style.py#L817):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

def background_gradient(s, m, M, cmap='PuBu', low=0, high=0):
    rng = M - m
    norm = colors.Normalize(m - (rng * low),
                            M + (rng * high))
    normed = norm(s.values)
    c = [colors.rgb2hex(x) for x in plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap)(normed)]
    return ['background-color: %s' % color for color in c]

df = pd.DataFrame([[3,2,10,4],[20,1,3,2],[5,4,6,1]])
df.style.apply(background_gradient,
               cmap='PuBu',
               m=df.min().min(),
               M=df.max().max(),
               low=0,
               high=0.2)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I use the style in a loop? I have a Dictionary in which the value is dataFrame. I would like to loop through the Dictionary and Show the DataFrame with style. @Guilherme Beltramini

Comment: @JasonLi, if your `dict` with `pandas.DataFrame` is like this `dict_dfs = {'df1': pd.DataFrame(...), 'df2': pd.DataFrame(...), ...}`, you can do use `from IPython.display import display` and put `display(df.style.apply(...))` inside a for-loop (e.g., `for df in dict_dfs.values()`) (obs.: since it's not possible to use block-formatting for code inside the comments, I had to simplify the examples, but I hope it's clear).

Comment: It works after upgrading pandas from 0.19 to 0.24. Thanks @Guiherme Beltramini

Answer (score 18):

Setting `axis=None` is working for me in 1.0.5

Answer (score 15):

You can use `axis=None` to get rid of the min and max computations in the call:

```
def background_gradient(s, m=None, M=None, cmap='PuBu', low=0, high=0):
    print(s.shape)
    if m is None:
        m = s.min().min()
    if M is None:
        M = s.max().max()
    rng = M - m
    norm = colors.Normalize(m - (rng * low),
                            M + (rng * high))
    normed = s.apply(norm)

    cm = plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap)
    c = normed.applymap(lambda x: colors.rgb2hex(cm(x)))
    ret = c.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: %s' % x)
    return ret


df.style.apply(background_gradient, axis=None)
```

Edit: You may need to use `normed = s.apply(lambda x: norm(x.values))` for [this to work on matplotlib 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518229/python-3-break-pandas-style-for-gradients-singleblockmanager-is-cause)

Answer (score 6):

You need to set axis to None. For me best solution using seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
cm = sns.color_palette("blend:white,green", as_cmap=True)
df.style.background_gradient(cmap = cm,axis=None)
```