# Strange cmap background_gradient behavior

Tags: python, pandas

I found and am using @mrandrewandrade [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42323184/1215012) to display the correlation coefficients of the boston housing data using a styled panda dataframe in an iPython notebook when I've noticed that the color mapping used in the `background_gradient()` isn't calculating correctly for the `CHAS` data.
It also looks like some of the values in the `B` data are affected as well.

Its correct in the axis passed into the `background_gradient(cmap, axis=1)` command but not the other axis. The row axis will work is you change that line to `axis=0`. All the other table cells seem to calculate fine.

Can someone help figure out the problem, I'm stumped as to what is happening and how to avoid it?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# load Boston housing data into a dataframe
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston = load_boston()
bos = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)
bos['MEDV'] = boston.target
bos.head()
```

[image]

```
# using a styled panda's dataframe from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42323184/1215012
cmap = 'coolwarm'

def magnify():
    return [dict(selector="th", props=[("font-size", "7pt")]),
            dict(selector="td", props=[('padding', "0em 0em")]),
            dict(selector="th:hover", props=[("font-size", "12pt")]),
            dict(selector="tr:hover td:hover", 
                 props=[('max-width', '200px'), ('font-size', '12pt')])
]

corr.style.background_gradient(cmap, axis=1)\
    .set_properties(**{'max-width': '80px', 'font-size': '10pt'})\
    .set_caption("Hover to magify")\
    .set_precision(2)\
    .set_table_styles(magnify())
```

[image]

To help highlight the issue here is the same data plotted as a seaborn heatmap:

```
# calculating and plotting the correlation coeff's using a seaborn heatmap
corr = bos.corr()
sns.heatmap(corr, xticklabels=corr.columns, yticklabels=corr.columns, cmap='coolwarm')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found this question by having the same issue. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42563850) solved my problem.

In short, it seems there is no way to use the actual backgroud_gradient DataFrame method, but is not too complicated to achieve the effect you're looking for with a custom function.