# apply color to the cells based on the value in cell in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

[image]

**working code**

```
 import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import colors,cm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

filename = r'c:\Users\91956\Desktop\time_50.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename,index_col=0)
select_col = df.columns[1:]

cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["red","white", "green"])

def background_gradient(s, cmap='PuBu', low=0, high=0):
    s = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce') #<-- here, string will become nan.
    m = s.min() #<---------- here
    M = s.max() #<-----------here
    rng = M - m
    norm = colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=m - (rng * low), vcenter=0., vmax=M + (rng * high))
    normed = norm(s.values)
    c = [colors.rgb2hex(x) for x in plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap)(normed)]
    return ['background-color: %s' % color for color in c]

S = df.style.apply( background_gradient,
                    cmap=cmap,
                    low=0.5,
                    high=0.5,
                    subset= pd.IndexSlice[:, select_col],
                    axis=1
                )

html = S.render()
with open("output.html","w") as fp:
    fp.write(html)
```

i was getting this error

File "c:\Users\91956\Desktop\asdf.py", line 29, in 
m=df.min().min(),
File "C:\Users\91956\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 11468, in stat_func
return self._reduce(
File "C:\Users\91956\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4248, in _reduce
return op(delegate, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
File "C:\Users\91956\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 129, in f
result = alt(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
File "C:\Users\91956\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 873, in reduction
result = getattr(values, meth)(axis)
File "C:\Users\91956\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_methods.py", line 43, in _amin
return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'

**update 2**
did necessary changes. was able to get required output.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that that the median of your value range is not zero. Try setting `low, high` when calling `background_gradient` [info](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.core.style.Styler.background_gradient.html)

Comment: what should be high and low such that zero will be median, eg values like low =  -5 and high = 5?

Comment: it doesnt work.

Comment: I have updated my answer @AniketPatil: check it

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: i will update you once i get it right. thank you for your help.

Comment: it is working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42563850/6660373) will help and also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528097/6660373).

To create sample df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],
               axis=1)
df.iloc[3, 3] = np.nan
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan
```

---

```
from matplotlib import colors

cmap=LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('rg',["r","w","g"], N=256) 

def background_gradient(s, m, M, cmap='PuBu', low=0, high=0):
    s = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce') #<-- here, string will become nan.
    print(s)
    rng = M - m
    norm = colors.DivergingNorm(vmin=m - (rng * low), vcenter=0., vmax=M + (rng * high))
    normed = norm(s.values)
    c = [colors.rgb2hex(x) for x in plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap)(normed)]
    return ['background-color: %s' % color for color in c]

x = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') #<--- here string will be converted to `NaN` so that I can find out the max and min value.
df.style.apply(background_gradient,
               cmap=cmap,
               m=x.min().min(),
               M=x.max().max(),
               low=0.5,
               high=0.5, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, ['B', 'C']]
              )
```

---

[image]

Edit:

pass `subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, ['B', 'C']]` to apply <-- I want to apply colour on `B` and `C` column.

```
df.style.apply(background_gradient,
               cmap=cmap,
               m=df.min().min(),
               M=df.max().max(),
               low=0.5,
               high=0.5, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, ['B', 'C']]
              )
```

### Edit2:

```
from matplotlib import colors

cmap=LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('rg',["r","w","g"], N=256) 

def background_gradient(s, cmap='PuBu', low=0, high=0):
    s = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
    m = s.min() #<---------- here
    M = s.max() #<-----------here
    rng = M - m
    norm = colors.DivergingNorm(vmin=m - (rng * low), vcenter=0., vmax=M + (rng * high))
    normed = norm(s.values)
    c = [colors.rgb2hex(x) for x in plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap)(normed)]
    return ['background-color: %s' % color for color in c]

# x = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df.style.apply(background_gradient,
               cmap=cmap,
               low=0.5,
               high=0.5, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, ['B', 'C', 'D']],  axis=1
              )
```

Use `axis=1` in apply (along column wise comparison for each row)

---

[image]

Comment: what is s in  norm(s.values)

Comment: @AniketPatil: s is your dataFrame df's elements

Comment: pass `subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, ['B', 'C']]` check the edited answer. you can select row also using this or only columns you want to pass you can pass a column name list to the subset. You can modify this code as per your need :)

Comment: df that i am using is shown in picture, it contains str data as well ticker column, i tried to modify my code, but not able to get desired output, i have updated the question with the code i am using

Comment: can you tell me what are the necessary changes to get desired result?

Comment: Check I have updated and look at arrow one code.

Comment: m and M values should get calculated for each row

Comment: see Edit2. Can't help further now :) This will be enuf I guess. Now you can modify as per your need. @AniketPatil: What error?

Comment: see my code in the question i was using axis = 1 before you mentioned, error is TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'

Comment: you missed this : `s = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')`  . change the row to numeric type and make string as nan and then perform everything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226117/discussion-between-aniket-patil-and-pygirl).

Comment: Very complete answer! Nice!

Comment: @CeliusStingher: Thanks :') . If you don't mind can I connect to you on linkedin. I will get to know a lot of thing from you guys TmT.